# Размещение 2 блоков

Tags: bootstrap4, adaptive-design

Имеется 2 блока на страничке, стоящие рядом в 1 строке, при уменьшении экрана второй блок должен становиться под первый. Не могу решить данную проблему (новечек в бутстрапе).  Подскажите пожалуйста оптимальное решение (пробовала подставлять классы .col-lg-6 .col-md-6 но на большом экране второй блок сразу перескакивает под первый, а надо только на меньших размерах)

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашла! Подставила другие классы все таки col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 подошло

Comment: Это здорово, но для других посетителей вопрос вряд ли будет полезен: нет ни кода вопроса, ни кода ответа.